# calculate the position of a point x knowing the distance from one point a and another point b

Tags: geometry

i am trying to calculate the position of a point given the distance from another point and that it is at a right angle to another point. a picture makes it easier to see

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlZ5T.jpg)

this is to try and create a corridor along a GPS path but each one broken down like above
so given the position of A = 1,1 and B = 3,3  and distance d = 1 how would i calculate x ?

Comment: The information looks too minimal tbh

Comment: $X$ is $(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$.

Comment: Shouldn't there be two answers?

Comment: what is the formula for that answer ?   @velut yes there are would be two answers, one above and one below. the pic was just for simplicity

Comment: @velutluna yes, but the way he drew it, i found that one.

Comment: @samjoe, what was the formula you used ?

Comment: @user2168435 simple geometry. We have essentially a right isosceles triangle with hypotenuse as $1$ unit.

Comment: thats not making any sense, with regards to A, B and d what is what in your method

Comment: @user2168435 ok. btw d is one as you mentioned.

Comment: yes, d = 1 but your method of Xx being 1- 1/sq2  what where are the numbers you used from ?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the lower point as $A (x_a,y_a)$ and the other one to be $B(x_b,y_b)$ and I assume them to be known.

Let the point you need be $P$ $(x,y)$.

Now, $PA\perp AB$
therefore, you can use that   $ m_{PA}\times m_{AB}=-1$ (Where $m$ means slope of the line).

This will give you one equation in $x$ and $y$.

Assuming that $d$ is also given, apply $PA=d$ using basic coordinate geometry.

I believe the method I'm suggesting shall give you your answer (Actually shall provide you with 2 possible positions)

Comment: sorry to be a pain but how would i apply that to A, B and d. its been 10 plus years since algebra ..........